# redirect the users based on their ip to a language every time they visit my website with the ability to switch lang after redirection?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpml

I have a Wordpress site using WPML for Multilang, I have three languages on the site with subdirectories option ( /fr , /en , /de ).

Example: If a user is in Germany I want to redirect him to "/de" and still give him the ability to switch to another language

I found some plugins like "IP2Location" but all plugins like that keep redirecting the user to his current country language and never be able to switch to another language

I tried doing it with javascript by applying cookies but that have a problem too it will redirect users once a day and not every time they come back to the site

Comment: Please don't use geolocation to guess a user's language. [Browsers tell you what their system language is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language). It's really annoying to have a laptop configured with an English OS, an English browser UI, and to be shoved to a Spanish language version of a website just because you're on holiday there.

Comment: Can you propose any solution to do that based on browser language ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the best solution for it. You can try it now it will be work. Just replace your country code and website url.

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

add_action('wp', 'ak_redirect_on_ip_base');

function ak_redirect_on_ip_base()
{
$my_current_lang = apply_filters('wpml_current_language', NULL);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=" . getRealIpAddr());
   // echo $xml->geoplugin_countryName;

//It will return country code
   echo $xml->geoplugin_countryCode;
   

    if ($xml->geoplugin_countryCode ==  'DE' && $my_current_lang != 'de') {
        header('Location: http://www.youdomain.com/de');
    } elseif ($xml->geoplugin_countryCode ==  'fr'  && $my_current_lang != 'fr') {
        header('Location: http://www.youdomain.com/fr');
    } else {
        header('Location: http://www.youdomain.com/');
    };
    die;
}

//uncomment this code and see all the variable into this array to match best condition 

/*foreach ($xml as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, "= ", $value,  " \n";
}
echo "</pre>";
*/
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the script or add some comments please ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @HichamMIFTAH I replaced my old code with easy way. please have a test with it.

Comment: If its working fine for you please make as done this answer. Thank you!!